# Pandas: How to control display options for columns that has arrays/lists inside them?

Tags: python, pandas

As above. I tried all options, both from numpy and pandas, to no avail.

The options are defined for columns that have float, or int, but never arrays, and I don't see any way to control them.

[image]

Comment: save array and list the dataframe cell is not a good way

Comment: @YOBEN_S It is really short, just three elements.

Comment: @YOBEN_S is definitely right - if the arrays are all three elements then they should be three columns. Pandas is storing arrays of pointers to python objects which are pointing to arrays of floats. This will have very poor performance compared to three float arrays. Additionally, you won't be able to utilize any of the functionality for which pandas is designed. If you really do need to do this, can you explain what you're actually hoping to achieve? There's no general purpose list-in-cell formatting library.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Thanks. No ultimate goal. It's just that this list has a name `Resonances` If I split it, it would be rather inconvenient to give seprate coloumn name for each one, but I guess I will have to do it. Now I realize I was doing something not the correct way.

Comment: Sounds good :) I think you'll find pandas much easier to use managing lists of columns rather than columns of lists. Best of luck!